# Why does MSBuild suddenly say my <Target> has no outputs during a Visual Studio rebuild?

Tags: msbuild

I have a target "B" that depends on a target "A". Target "A" creates an item, which target B has as its `Inputs` and also uses as its Outputs (with a transformation using custom metadata created for the item in target "A").

```
<Target Name="A" Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ConfigTemplates Include="@(ContentWithTargetPath)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.template'">
            <Original>%(FullPath)</Original>
            <Destination>$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)%(TargetPath)</Destination>
        </ConfigTemplates>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="B" 
    AfterTargets="AfterBuild"
    DependsOnTargets="A"
    Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'"
    Inputs="@(ConfigTemplates)"
    Outputs="@(ConfigTemplates->'%(Destination)')">
    ...
</Target>
```

This works fine and it fully supports incremental builds (is a 'source' changes target "B" is executed, otherwise it is skipped).

However, as soon as I create a target "C" that also depends on target "A", suddenly target "B" is always skipped because it "has no outputs".

```
<Target Name="C"
    AfterTargets="AfterBuild"
    DependsOnTargets="A"
    Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'">
    ...
</Target>
```

Why would that be the case?

And this begs a more general question: is this the correct way to dynamically provide an item for more than one task?

Edit:
I tried to turn it around by removing the DependsOnTargets and putting a `BeforeTargets="B;C"` on target "A". But the result is the same.

Edit:
**Important** I have found that the problem is a **rebuild** as performed by Visual Studio. Apparently during a rebuild this particular configuration causes the "has no outputs" for target "B". Is it because during a rebuild target "C" comes before target "B", and somehow 'invalidates' the ConfigTemplates?

Comment: You might want to try posting this question at MS forum to get a more professional response: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/home?forum=msbuild

Comment: It's a bit hard to test this as-is. Could you post a minimal working sample including what the dir structure has to look like, the value of ContentWithTargetPath etc?

Answer (score 1):

TIP1: Try to add exception to your anti-virus. I've noticed that some of them (as my Avast!) used to prevent Visual Studio from building for some reason.

TIP2: If you are using "A" output for "B" and "C", try to add

```
"BeforeTargets="C"
```

to "B", to be sure that it is built in correct order. From your description it appears that "C" is somehow performed before "B".